# sendFile скачивает файл, при расширении файла "php"

Tags: javascript, php, express, socket.io

Пытаюсь открыть клиенту при подключении к серверу файл с интерфейсом. При расширении файла HTML - страница открывается и все хорошо, но, если поставить файлу расширение `.php`, то файл просто загружается на носитель клиента. Попытался скачать [php-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-express), но проблему это не решило.

---

Вот код:

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var phpExpress = require('php-express')({
    // assumes php is in your PATH
    binPath: 'php'
});

// set view engine to php-express
app.set('views', './views');
app.engine('php', phpExpress.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'php');

// routing all .php file to php-express
app.all(/.+\.php$/, phpExpress.router);

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = "localhost"//server.address().address;
    console.log(host);
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log(port);
    console.log('PHPExpress app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
//var server = require('http').createServer(app);

//server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.php');
});
```

Comment: Знаю что глупый вопрос, но у вас установлен PHP? Он должен быть установлен и присутствовать в PATH. Или задайте абсолютный путь к PHP

Comment: @ДавидМанжула, вопрос как оказалось совсем не глупый, по крайне мере он меня заставил задуматься над другими аспектами проблемы. В phpstorm разумеется у меня задан интерпретатор php 7.3, абсолютный путь также не помог, думаю ошибка в синтаксисе, какая нибудь глупая. А другой аспект вот в чем, когда я залью уже на хостинг, неужели мне придется скачивать php на мой сервер?

Comment: @ДавидМанжула, если будет возможность, попробуйте запустить, пожалуйста у себя, в случае успеха - я явно где-то облажался.

Comment: Да, вам нужно будет скачать php на ваш сервер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в последних строчках явно задано: если пользователь обратится по адресу `/` - прочитай с диска файл `index.php` и отдай ему:

```
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.php');
});
```

Этот код нужно удалить.

---

В строке `app.set('views', './views')` вы задаете движку папку, где должны лежать файлы которые будут отображатся. И именно там `php-express` будет искать `.php`-файлы.

Таким образом, нужно переместить `php`-файлы в папку `./views` (хотя, если в этой папке будут только `php`-файлы, советую пеерименовать папку на что-то соответствующее).

---

Тогда остается одна проблема: движок отзывается только по адресам `....php`, если перейти по адресу `localhost:3000/` - в адресе нету `.php` и `express` не передаст запрос `php`.

Поэтому я добавил строчку `app.all('/', phpExpress.router)` - она добавляет соответствующий адрес на управление `php-express`.

---

В итоге, получился вот такой код:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var phpExpress = require('php-express')({
  // assumes php is in your PATH
  binPath: 'php'
});

// set view engine to php-express
app.set('views', './views');
app.engine('php', phpExpress.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'php');

// routing all .php file to php-express
app.all(/.+\.php$/, phpExpress.router);
app.all('/', phpExpress.router);

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = "localhost"//server.address().address;
  console.log(host);
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log(port);
  console.log('PHPExpress app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```